# me / myself which should be used?

Tags: sentence-meaning

If I advise myself,  what will it be entitled?

1. 'Advice for myself'
2. 'Advice for me'

Comment: It is incorrect in English to have spaces before punctuation like commas, questions marks, periods and close quotes. Without more details for how you are using this to be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are giving *yourself* the advice (something I didn't notice at first), "myself" is better.  Which is also why I didn't write "since you are giving you the advice":  it's a reflexive sentence, and thus needs the "self" form of the pronoun.